# Android API < 10 replacement for getType method

Tags: android, sqlite, select, dynamic, gettype

I'm working on a way to get my select method for the SQLite database 'fully' dynamic for the API I'm building. The one and last problem at this moment is the fact that I can't tell the type of the item which is returned from the query.
I've tried a couple of things suggested in other topics but none of them seem te work for me.

The way it is used right now, it says: everything is a String. I know this works for int's and Strings but I'm not sure about other formats and offcourse it's not the way it's supposed to be.
Also this code only works with one record at the moment, but that's not a problem.

```
public HashMap<String, String> select(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
    columns = cursor.getColumnNames(); //Used when columns[] are null - SELECT * FROM ...
    HashMap<String, String> resultTable = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            resultTable.put(columns[i], cursor.getString(i));
        }
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return resultTable;
}
```

I'm working in android api version 10, so getType isn't available

Answer (score 0):

first of all check the type of data of that column data.. with the help of..

```
cursor.getType(columnIndex)
```

check the returned value with...

```
cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT  // or cursor.FIELD_XXXXXXX
```

then use the getXXXX() method respectively..

Comment: I can't use this method since I'm working with API level 10 as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

try this

sstatic int getType(Cursor cursor, int i) throws Exception 
    {
        SQLiteCursor sqLiteCursor = (SQLiteCursor) cursor;
        CursorWindow cursorWindow = sqLiteCursor.getWindow(); 
        int pos = cursor.getPosition(); int type = -1; 
        if (cursorWindow.isNull(pos, i))
        { 
            type = FIELD_TYPE_NULL;
        } else if (cursorWindow.isLong(pos, i)) 
        { 
            type = FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER; } 
        else if (cursorWindow.isFloat(pos, i))
        {
            type = FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT; 
        }
        else if (cursorWindow.isString(pos, i))
        { 
            type = FIELD_TYPE_STRING; 
        }
        else if (cursorWindow.isBlob(pos, i))
        {
            type = FIELD_TYPE_BLOB; 
        }
        return type; 
    }

Comment: the cast fails with `java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sqlcipher.CrossProcessCursorWrapper`